# redirect STDOUT of a command to a file and decide based on it in linux bash

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to run `netstat` command and redirect `stderr` and `stdout` to a text file and check out its `stdout` for a specific string. I don't want to open the resulted text file and look for a string, instead looking for a better approach. How should I do it in a bash script?

```
while true
    netstat -anpt 1>>./log.txt 2>>./log.txt
    if [ $1 | grep -q "631" ]; then
        # whatever to be done
        break
    fi
done
```

Comment: `[ $1 | grep -q "631" ]` doesn't make sense. `[]` is for testing conditional expressions, not running programs.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of your code. `[ $1 |` should produce an error message.

Comment: You say "I don't want to open the resulted text file and look for a string". Why? That is, you should tell us why examining the content of the file containing the output of the command is undesirable even though you captured the output in a file.

Comment: @KurtisRader Because if you look at the infinite loop, you'll notice that the output file would be grown in size and looking for a string inside ever-growing file doesn't make sense to me, at least. We have to keep this file for reasons, and also check out the presence of the "631". This is the whole purpose of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You send stdout to log.txt. If you want to check the stdout for a certain string, you can do a

```
if grep -q 631 log.txt
```

I don't see a reason why you don't want to have a look into log.txt, since you are creating it anyway, but if you really want to avoid this, you can do a

```
if netstat -antp 2>log_stderr.txt | tee log_stdout.txt | grep -q 631
```

This leaves you with `log_stdout.txt` holding the standard error, `log_stderr.txt` holding the standard error, and the grep is checking for the pattern without opening the standard output log file.

If you want to have stdin and stdout combined, you can do of course a

```
if netstat -antp  2>&1 | tee log.txt | grep -q 631
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What you explained, solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the output in a variable using command substitution, while also redirecting to a file with `tee`.

```
output=$(netstat -anpt 2>&1 | tee -a ./log.txt)
if [[ "$output" = *631* ]]; then
    # whatever
fi
```

Comment: May I ask ```"$output" =~ *631*```, checks out the content of ./log.txt or just the result of the ```netstat```?

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake. `=~` performs a regexp test, but `*631*` is a glob pattern. To compare with a glob it has to use `=`, and we need to use the `[[ ]]` bash extension.